# How to send reactive values from Shiny App into global environment for review?

Tags: r, shiny, environment-variables, shiny-reactivity

The below example code uses a module structure to pass values from the main server to two modules `mod1` and `mod2` where the values are manipulated and passed back and forth between the modules. This is for learning purposes.

I use `common <- reactiveValues()` in the main server and then assign values to common$xyz inside the modules, which is then accessible inside all of the modules. The code works as intended: when running, the top of the Shiny window shows a base dataframe `df`, the user uses a slider input to specify the value to multiply the base `df` by with results rendered in the 2nd table, the 3rd table adds 10 to each of the second table's values and sends it's column A back to the 2nd table to be appended to the end of the 2nd table, and then the 2nd table's last column is multiplied by 100 and sent back to the 3rd table to be appended to its end. This is for practicing sending data back and forth between modules.

My question: how can I send the complete `common` reactive object to the global environment for testing and review purposes? As I build out this code I need to have a complete view into how this `common` object is evolving.

In the below code I tried this using: `oe1 <- reactive({common})` and `observeEvent(oe1(),{common.R <<- oe1()})` in the main server section, but all I get back is:

```
> common.R
<ReactiveValues> 
  Values:    colA_mod2, df, mod1_dat, mod2_table, svc 
  Readonly:  FALSE
```

which doesn't tell me much. I would like to see the entire `common` object with all values and elements that are housed in it. I would rather retrieve the object in the manner I just described rather than seeing it scroll by the R Studio console when using a `print()` statement, because the `common` object I am working towards will be very large.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

mod1_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df <- common$df
      svc <- common$svc()
      df * as.numeric(svc)
    })
    
    observe({
      common$mod1_dat <- new_dat()
      common$colA_mod2 <- common$mod2_table$A
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      dat <- new_dat()
      dat$colA_mod2 <- common$colA_mod2 
      dat
    })
  })
}

mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

mod2_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      mod1_dat <- common$mod1_dat
      dat <- data.frame(mod1_dat + 10) 
      if (!is.null(common$colA_mod2)) {
        dat$colA_mod2_mod1 <- common$colA_mod2 * 100
      }
      common$mod2_table <- dat
      dat
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("table"),
    sliderInput("svc", "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    mod1_ui("mod1"),
    mod2_ui("mod2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  common <- reactiveValues(df = data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4))
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(common$df)})
  common$svc <- reactive(input$svc)
  mod1_server("mod1", common)
  mod2_server("mod2", common)
  
  oe1 <- reactive({common})
  observeEvent(oe1(),{common.R <<- oe1()})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The direct answer to *"How to send reactive values from Shiny App into global environment"* is [`assign(x, value, envir=globalenv())`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `browser()`? If you haven't, what it does is that, when you run your Shiny app on RStudio, it *pauses* your Shiny app at the place you put the `browser()` function, then gives you access to the console inside the current environment in which your Shiny app is running, thus allowing you to directly check the objects you need. Then, you can resume the app using the controls above the console. I use this all the time by placing `browser()` at the beginning of `reactive({})` calls to check if data is correct before plotting or further processing, or to quickly test plots using values from inputs.